# Using Sharpen to convert java to C#

Tags: c#, java, eclipse, ant, converters

I have a problem using Sharpen.
I followed [this link](http://web.archive.org/web/20131202022757/http://www.pauldb.me/post/14916717048/a-guide-to-sharpen-a-great-tool-for-converting-java) step by step.

There is a silly thing here not related to Sharpen but to Ant I guess.

It gives me:

```
Buildfile: C:\Users\Peyman\Workspace\MyZoneCore\src\run-sharpen.xml
clean:
sharpen-docs:
     [exec] Error: Could not find or load main class org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main

BUILD FAILED
C:\Users\Peyman\Workspace\MyZoneCore\src\run-sharpen.xml:59: The following error occurred while executing this line:
C:\Users\Peyman\Workspace\MyZoneCore\src\run-sharpen.xml:20: exec returned: 1

Total time: 780 milliseconds
```

BUILD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project name="Db4objects.Db4odoc" default="sharpen-docs">
<property file="sharpen.properties" />

<macrodef name="reset-dir">
    <attribute name="dir" />
    <sequential>
        <delete dir="@{dir}" />
        <mkdir dir="@{dir}" />
    </sequential>
</macrodef>

<echo message="${eclipse.startup.jar}"></echo>

<macrodef name="sharpen">
    <attribute name="workspace" />
    <attribute name="resource" />


    <element name="args" optional="yes" />

    <sequential>
        <exec executable="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_31\bin\java.exe" failonerror="true" timeout="1800000">
            <arg value="-Xms256m" />
            <arg value="-Xmx512m" />
            <arg value="-cp" />
            <arg value="${eclipse.startup.jar}" />
            <arg value="org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main" />
            <arg value="-data" />
            <arg file="@{workspace}" />
            <arg value="-application" />
            <arg value="sharpen.core.application" />
            <arg value="-header" />
            <arg file="header.txt" />
            <arg value="@{resource}" />

            <args />

        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>


<!-- Main target -->
<target name="sharpen-docs" depends="clean">

<property name="target.dir" location="sharpen" />

<!-- Copy java files to the resource folder -->
<copy todir="${target.dir}/sharpened/src">

  <!-- CHECK THIS SETTING 
       Make sure that the fileset dir below points to the root folder 
       containing the Java source code files you want to convert to C#
  -->
  <fileset dir="src">
    <include name="**/*.java" />
  </fileset>
</copy>

    <!-- Sharpen java files -->
<sharpen workspace="${target.dir}" resource="sharpened/src">
  <args>

    <!-- CHECK THIS SETTING 
       Make sure that you have an arg value/path element for 
       EVERY external jar file that your Java project references.
       You can get the list of these by right clicking on the project,
       choosing Build Path -> Configure Build Path, and then checking the Libraries tab.
    -->
    <!-- classpath needed for java sources compilation -->
    <arg value="-cp" />
    <arg path="C:/eclipse/workspace/myproject/libs/kxml2-2.3.0.jar" />
    <arg value="-cp" />
    <arg path="C:/eclipse/workspace/myproject/libs/regexp-me.jar" />

    <!-- Sharpen options are defined in a separate file -->
    <arg value="@sharpen-all-options" />
  </args>
</sharpen>
```

Comment: Do you have eclipse installed?

Comment: Which version of eclipse are you using?  just to be clear - you're running the build from eclipse, not from the commandline?

Comment: Eclipse 4.2.1 JUNO on Windows 7

Comment: I actually see the file my self in the C:/Users/Peyman/Desktop/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.3.0.v20120522-1813 in org>eclipse>equinox>luncher>Main

Comment: There is a build file for ant called run-sharpen.xml I shared it in new edit.